# Stripe session creation for subscription to product with multiple prices

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I'm using the following option to create a Stripe session and it work fine, however there may be a case where a user would subscribe to a product which has multiple prices depending on location, currency etc.

Is it possible to amend the option to allow the user to choose the price from a list of possible product prices, or is there another way to achieve this?

thanks

```
    var options = new SessionCreateOptions
    {
        SuccessUrl = successUrl,
        CancelUrl = cancelUrl,
        Mode = "subscription",
        AllowPromotionCodes = true,
        LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
        {
            new SessionLineItemOptions
            {
                Price = Request.Form["priceId"],
                Quantity = 1,
            },
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way in Checkout to show a list of currencies and let the user choose. Instead you can create multi-currency Prices as described [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/present-local-currencies#create-multi-currency-prices) which will be used as a Presentment local currency to the customer in the Checkout Session. You can read through [this](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/present-local-currencies#checkout-experience) to have a better sense of the flow